# How are ES6 modules used with app.get in a Node/Express routing application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I decided to use the new ES6 export instead of using module export in a NodeJS/Express project. I was reading the MDN documentation and it says export is used like so:

```
export function draw(ctx, length, x, y, color) {
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, length, length);
```

Here I am trying to use it in the same way in this `app.get` function but my editor throws a syntax error. Is there a different format I'm supposed to use? - I am essentially trying to seperate route containers into separate files for organization - and then import them back to my main app.js file in the end for route declaration with express.

```
 export app.post('/exampleroute', async (req, res) => {
   ...
 });

// Error: Declaration or Statement expected.
```

Comment: What kind of binding were you trying to export there? How would you want to import and use that route? What is `app` (i.e. where is it coming from)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to export a *value* (either a default one or a named variable).

The return value of `app.post()` isn't useful.

Either export the function:

```
export const myRouteHandler = async (req, res) => {
   ...
};
```

and then:

```
import { myRouteHandler } from "./myModule";
app.post('/exampleroute', myRouteHandler)
```

or, export a router:

```
import express from 'express';
export const router = express.Router();

router.post('/exampleroute', async (req, res) => {
   ...
});
```

and then import and use that:

```
import { router } from "./myModule";
app.use("/", router);
```

Comment: One more followup question? Say I have dependencies used by the router post function in the first answer. Is it possible for me to include those dependencies in the file that the router.post module is being exported in? - Instead of putting the dependencies in the original exported module file? By dependencies I mean like (const, require fs etc.)

Comment: Dependencies don't leak between modules. You have to import the value into the scope where you use it.